# Difficulties with shortest.paths and Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, igraph, shortest-path

I am trying to get all the shortest paths between two nodes with the help of a transition matrix. 
The matrix isn't symmetric because the graph isn't directed. I have used the following code:

```
g <- graph.adjacency(DDGraph, weighted=TRUE, mode="directed")
str(g)
      [1]   1->  2   2->  3   4-> 40   5->  6   6->164   7->  8   8-> 46   9-> 10  10->121  11-> 12  12-> 13  12->174  13-> 14  14->  1  15-> 18  16-> 17  18-> 16
s.paths <- shortest.paths(g, algorithm = "dijkstra")
```

Now, the last output is a matrix which is supposed to give the distances between two nodes calculated with the Dijkstra Algorithm. But what I get is a `symmetric matrix` which it shouldn't be. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
When I use the Johnson Algorithm the matrix isn't symmetric and from what I can tell it works just fine.
It might be helpful to know that you can't reach every node from every node, so there will be a lot of "Inf" entries. Again, with the `Johnson Algorithm` it works, but not with the `Dijkstra` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the `mode` parameter of `shortest.paths`, which is supposed to tell igraph whether the edge directions are to be considered or not. I think that `mode="all"` is the default and it does not consider edge directions since it allows an edge to be traversed in both directions. Try `mode="out"` instead.